# Как получить новый объект без свойства?

Tags: javascript

Как отфильтровать объект по ключу?

Есть объект:

```
name: 'fffggfg'
surname: 'fhfhfhfg'
about: 'kdfkdfk'
```

Нужно получить новый объект без свойства `about`.

Comment: а если без delete/ c filter можно как-нибудь?
delete нельзя. плохая практика

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С filter:

```js
const source = {
  name: 'fffggfg',
  surname: 'fhfhfhfg',
  about: 'kdfkdfk'
}

console.log(
    Object.keys(source)
          .filter(key => key !== 'about')
          .reduce( (res, key) => { res[key] = source[key]; return res; }, {})
);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Клонировать: `var result = Object.assign({}, soruce);`
2. Удалить не нужное поле `delete result.about;`

   ```
   var result = Object.assign({}, soruce);
   delete result.about;
   console.log(result);
   ```

Почитать об [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) и о [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) можно на MDN.

Альтернатива (см. комментарии)

```
var source = {
    name: 'fffggfg',
    surname: 'fhfhfhfg',
    about: 'kdfkdfk',
};

function copyWithout(src, exclude) {
    var result = {};
    for (prop in src) {
        prop !== exclude && (result[prop] = src[prop]);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(copyWithout(source, 'about'));
```

Comment: а если без delete/ c filter можно как-нибудь?
delete нельзя. плохая практика

Comment: Можно проитерировать все проперти объекта и перенести только нужные. Но тут есть нюанс со вложенными объектами. Они будут разделены новым и старым объектом. Вот for..in конструкция
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: у меня нет вложенных. как это сделать?

Comment: @werty "плохая практика" - это то, что вы пытаетесь сделать, независимо от способа. А само по себе решение через delete - нормальное.

Answer (score 1):

Можно, например, так:

```
function filterProps(obj, props) {
  var result = {};
  for (key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    if (props.indexOf(key) === -1) {
      result[key] = obj[key];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var foo = {
  name: 'fffggfg',
  surname: 'fhfhfhfg',
  about: 'kdfkdfk'
}

console.log(filterProps(foo, ['about']));
```

Рабочий [пример на JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/687ve3bp/1/)